# Type problems while generating a list of random numbers in range in haskell and ghci

Tags: haskell, recursion, random, range

Heyhey stackoverflowers,

As a PHP Developer, I've learned so much about coding. Used it for developing with Python, which is a very easy to learn coding language. Not at university ve have to write some code with Haskell, which is something really different to me..

One of our tasks is to write a random generator. I can explain it:

My idea was to generate a List with randomNumbers.

Lets say:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.Random

// max random numbers
maxInt = 5
// list
randList = replicateM (fromIntegral maxInt) (randomRIO(1, 6))
```

This code is working fine in GHCI using `let` to define `maxInt` and `randList`, but in my `.hs` file to interpret, it does not work..

Errors here are:

```
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (Num a0)
    arising from the literal `1' at code.hs:11:59
  (Random a0)
    arising from a use of `randomRIO'
    at code.hs:11:49-57
Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
  randList :: IO [a0] (bound at code.hs:11:1)
Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
              or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
In the expression: 1
In the first argument of `randomRIO', namely `(1, 6)'
In the second argument of `replicateM', namely `(randomRIO (1, 6))'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I tried very different things like

```
import System.Random

addToList :: Int -> Int
addToList 0 = [randomRIO(1, 6)]
addToList n = [randomRIO(1, 6)] ++ addToList (n-1)
```

but I am really new to Haskell and as a PHP OOP Programmer, with not Type Problems for Ints, Floats, Lists, Arrays, Haskell is really stupid, for me ;)

Thank you!

Comment: there are no more lines of code :) yeah i thought that too because if i write the code directly in ghci, it works fine.. but loaded in ghci there are several bugs

Comment: I bet you _have_ had type problems in PHP, you just never recognised them as such because they inevitably end up as much harder to fix runtime bugs. Because Haskell is so much more _clever_ (perhaps sometimes "too clever", but definitely not stupid), this happens very seldom: in well-designed Haskell projects, you can often be almost sure that the code will work correctly if only it typechecks in the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs because numeric literals are overloaded in Haskell, so just writing `1` could mean it's an `Int`, a `Double` or some other numeric type depending on the context. If it's not fully determined by the context, Haskell will try to choose a type from a list of defaults, but only when this is deemed *safe<sup>1</sup>*, i.e. when the only type classes involved are standard ones.

`Random` is not one of the standard type classes, which is why it won't pick `Integer` as the default on its own. You have to add a type annotation yourself:

```
randList = replicateM (fromIntegral maxInt) (randomRIO (1 :: Integer, 6))
```

or

```
randList :: IO [Integer] 
randList = replicateM (fromIntegral maxInt) (randomRIO (1, 6))
```

[GHCi is less strict about this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules), which is why it worked there.

<sub><sup>1</sup> A user-defined class might in general do drastically different things for different types.</sub>

Comment: thank you, i think i need some more reading about haskell to learn it the right way.